# android - call_phone permission is required?

Tags: android

In my app i want to make a one tap call without using the **android.permission.CALL_PHONE**. is it possible? because of this permission user scare to install this app.

thanks

Comment: Is this a serious question? Permissions are there to show the user what your app is capable of. If you could bypass that the whole permission system would be pointless.

Comment: Yes @slukian is any other alternative is there for doing this?

Comment: @alextsc  how to do that?(pointless)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

pre-load the number you want to call in the dialer and leave pressing the "Call" button to the user. This does not require any extra permissions.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("tel:" + PhoneNumber));
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot invoke the phone without specifying that permission.  This is by design, to protect users from malicious apps.

Comment: is any other alternative is there for making a call without this?

Comment: @naresh, see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15842328/android-intent-action-call-uri/27522600#27522600