# Is it possible to make a direct call?

Tags: android

We know you can open a call application using this code:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("tel:0377778888")));
```

Is it possible to make a direct call without having to go through the default application of the device?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15842328/android-intent-action-call-uri

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code snippet makes the direct call:

```
// Check the SDK version and whether the permission is already granted or not.
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE}, PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_PHONE_CALL);
} else {
    //Open call function
    String phone = "7769942159";
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:+91" + phone));
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Use this permission in manifest:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />`

Comment: That was it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, You can do it by just  replacing `Intent.ACTION_DIAL` with `Intent.ACTION_CALL` in your code.
And you must need the CALL permission to the app.
For below Marshmallow devices you can make it by simply placing the below line in your manifest under manifest tag

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />`.

But for Marshmallow or above OS devices you need to declare the permission in manifest like below

```
<uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

And you need to ask the user Runtime permission for CALL_PHONE access.
To request permission

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHPNE})
```

To check permission

```
ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
                Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
```

For more info https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `ACTION_CALL`: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Answer (score 1):

```
 Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL,Uri.parse("tel:"+phno);
 startActivity(intent);
```

Android Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission>
```