# How to pass string value into dialpad

Tags: android, programmers-notepad

I have one activity and I wanna pass the static value to dialpad the value is *#000#.

Here is my `onClickListener` code :

```
  btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:*%23000"));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Comment: So you are facing any problem with above code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9685622/1027277

Comment: You are missing the last `%23`

Comment: when I add the last %23 then I recieve double *#000##